# Color fill in D3 gives error in If Loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, d3.js

I am try to fill colors conditionally but it seems ***if else*** loop is not entering the third condition.

Here is the working code but with some error in If Else statement

**code**

```
        var w = 400;
              var h = 40;
              var barPadding = 1;
              var heybaby = 10;

           var aa = 15;
           var bb = 17;
           var cc = 13;
           var dd = 8;
           var ee = 11;
           var ff = 19;
           var gg = 8;
           var hh = 15;
           var ii = 14;
           var jj = 15;
           var kk = 16;
           var ll = 11;
           var mm = 13;
           var nn = 12;

             var data1heatmap = [ aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj,kk, ll, mm, nn ];


              //Create SVG element
              var svg = d3.select("#chart1")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", "100%")
                    .attr("height", "100%")
                    .attr("viewBox","0 0 400 40")
                        .attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMinYMin meet")
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(1,1)");

              svg.selectAll("rect")
                 .data(data1heatmap)
                 .enter()
                 .append("rect")
                 .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / data1heatmap.length);
                 })
                 .attr("y", 0)
                 .attr("width", 25)
                 .attr("height", 25)
                 .attr("rx", 0)
                .attr("ry", 0)
                 .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
              if (i <= 5) {
            return "rgb(" + (d *5) + ", " + (d * 1) + ", " + (d * 1) + ")";
                    }
            else if (5 < i <= 9) {
            return "rgb(" + (d * 1) + ", " + (d * 3) + ", " + (d * 5) + ")";
            }
            else {
            return "rgb(" + (d * 2) + ", " + (d * 4) + ", " + (d * 2) + ")";
            }                      
            });
```

Here is the working fiddle [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/hawkeye15/vay86po8/)

I dont understand why it is not reading the last condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I don't whether I should post this as an answer.

But anyway, your else if statement is wrong.

```
else if (5 < i && i <= 9) {
                return "rgb(" + (d * 1) + ", " + (d * 3) + ", " + (d * 5) + ")";
}
```

**Your mistake :**

```
else if (5 < i <= 9)  // this will be always true if the value of i is greater than 5
```

So, it wan't entering the else condition.

Hope this helps.

```js
var w = 400;
          var h = 40;
          var barPadding = 1;
          var heybaby = 10;
        
       var aa = 15;
       var bb = 17;
       var cc = 13;
       var dd = 8;
       var ee = 11;
       var ff = 19;
       var gg = 8;
       var hh = 15;
       var ii = 14;
       var jj = 15;
       var kk = 16;
       var ll = 11;
       var mm = 13;
       var nn = 12;

         var data1heatmap = [ aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj,kk, ll, mm, nn ];


          //Create SVG element
          var svg = d3.select("#chart1")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%")
                .attr("viewBox","0 0 400 40")
                    .attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMinYMin meet")
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(1,1)");

          svg.selectAll("rect")
             .data(data1heatmap)
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
             .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / data1heatmap.length);
             })
             .attr("y", 0)
             .attr("width", 25)
             .attr("height", 25)
             .attr("rx", 0)
            .attr("ry", 0)
             .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
      if (i <= 5) {
     return "rgb(" + (d *5) + ", " + (d * 1) + ", " + (d * 1) + ")";
                }
    else if (5 < i && i <= 9) {
     return "rgb(" + (d * 1) + ", " + (d * 3) + ", " + (d * 5) + ")";
    }
    else {
        return "rgb(" + (d * 2) + ", " + (d * 4) + ", " + (d * 2) + ")";
    }           
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class = "col-md-6" id = "chart1" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var w = 400;
          var h = 40;
          var barPadding = 1;
          var heybaby = 10;
        
       var aa = 15;
       var bb = 17;
       var cc = 13;
       var dd = 8;
       var ee = 11;
       var ff = 19;
       var gg = 8;
       var hh = 15;
       var ii = 14;
       var jj = 15;
       var kk = 16;
       var ll = 11;
       var mm = 13;
       var nn = 12;

         var data1heatmap = [ aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj,kk, ll, mm, nn ];


          //Create SVG element
          var svg = d3.select("#chart1")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%")
                .attr("viewBox","0 0 400 40")
                    .attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMinYMin meet")
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(1,1)");

          svg.selectAll("rect")
             .data(data1heatmap)
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
             .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / data1heatmap.length);
             })
             .attr("y", 0)
             .attr("width", 25)
             .attr("height", 25)
             .attr("rx", 0)
            .attr("ry", 0)
             .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
      if (i <= 5) {
     return "rgb(" + (d *5) + ", " + (d * 1) + ", " + (d * 1) + ")";
                }
    else if (5 < i && i <= 9) {
     return "rgb(" + (d * 1) + ", " + (d * 3) + ", " + (d * 5) + ")";
    }
    else {
        return "rgb(" + (d * 2) + ", " + (d * 4) + ", " + (d * 2) + ")";
    }           
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class = "col-md-6" id = "chart1" >
```